# How to define a reusable folder path in Qt project file?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

When working with a Qt project file *.pro one can use for example the $$PWD to reference to the folder containing the project file.

Is there a possible way to define a custom folder path?

Like saying: $$CUSTOMFOLDER = /home/user/folder

I would like to define CUSTOMFOLDER once and then reuse it in the project file so that I dont always have to paste the long folder path. By That the code would also become more readable.

Comment: Just use `CUSTOMFOLDER = /home/user/folder`. Then you reuse it by using `$$CUSTOMFOLDER`

Comment: Appreciate your help, its working